# Background layer element lower (html/css)

Tags: html, css

I have a menu built with divs and I would like a menu item to have a lower layer background, in this case the body.

structure:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(path/body.png);
}

#menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mm {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fffl padding:5px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.mm.this {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="mm this">Home</div>
    <div class="mm">Contact</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

looks like this:

[image]

And you would like it to look like that: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this really. Here's one of many:

```
.mm.this {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -9999; /*remove this or set it to auto or a positive value*/
}

.mm.this:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
```

This creates a horizontal line and positions it at the bottom of the active tab. This will overlap the grey border beneath with a white line.